# Backoffice - View Database Itemtype Indexes

Tags: database, indexing, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

How to view the DB column indexes in backoffice? 
Suppose I have added 3 indexes like this on a custom itemtype ( defined in *-items.xml) like this:

```
         <itemtype generate="true" code="Model"..>
            <attributes>
            .......
            </attributes>
            <indexes>
                <index name="column1Idx">
                       <key attribute="column1" />
                </index>
                <index name="column2Idx">
                    <key attribute="column2" />
                </index>
                <index name="compositeIdx">
                    <key attribute="column1" />
                    <key attribute="column2" />
                </index>                
            </indexes>
            </itemtype>
```

Note I'm using HSQL DB for development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see any page for indexes in backoffice. But you can get them in hac. You can run below query in Console -> FlexibleSearch -> SQL Query tab.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

For getting columns in index you can use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
```

Comment: yeah. Backoffice doesn't have an option to see all the indexes. But the above query returns all table constraints, not the indexes.

Comment: You can filter by CONSTRAINT_TYPE.